# c++ "co_await" is undefined

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

I am new for c++
I've tried to use coroutine but I don't know why "co_await" is undefined
please help

thanks

```
#include "iostream"
#include "coroutine"

concurrency::task<void> MyFirstCoroutine()
{
    co_await(1000);// error said ""co_await" is undefined"
}
```

Comment: what compiler are you using, and which version, and have you turned ON, c++20 ? this is a relatively new feature, so it won't always compile on any compiler.

Comment: `co_await` was added in C++20 - what compiler flags are you using to select the C++ Standard version ? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

Comment: Additionally, for standard libraries, you should include them using `<` and `>`. i.e. `#include <coroutine>`

Comment: `100` does not have an overloaded operator co_await, to my knowledge. Are you sure `concurrency::task` supports this usage?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.7

Comment: That should default to c++14 and not c++20

Comment: You are new to C++ and you already tried coroutines? That is ambitious. I have been coding in C++ for more than 20 years, and for me C++20 coroutines are still a headache to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should set C++ version at C++20 or later in project settings